# Select distinct value from table with additional columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL (note the use of `distinct`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    question_id AS id,
    question_id AS object_id,
    created_at AS created,
    created_at AS lastmessage,
    'T' AS object_type
FROM
    responses
```

...this gives me...

[image]

I would like to get rid of the duplicate rows in the first column. What am I missing?

Comment: `DISTINCT` will eliminate duplicate rows, however I can see from your screenshot that these are **not** duplicate rows, just duplicate `question_id`. So as @Strawberry has pointed you too, read that post then rework your question. Please provide a MRE, sample data and explain what it is you are actually trying to achieve so that we can help you properly.

Comment: `DISTINCT` does not apply only to the first column -- it applies to _all_ the columns in your select-list. In other words, if there's any difference on the whole row from other rows in the result, it counts as a distinct row. This is a very common mistake SQL programmers make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation if you want one row per something.  Something like this:

```
SELECT question_id AS id, question_id AS object_id,
       MIN(created_at) AS created,
       MAX(created_at) AS lastmessage,
       'T' AS object_type
FROM responses
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon...you rock!    